# Possibility of replacement zero and his inverse by infinitesimals/infinities for non-problematic calculations

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, infinitesimals

**Is there any possibility to replace zero (null) and his inverse (quantity of zero raised to the power of negative one is indefinite) with an infinitesimal for calculations to avoid "zero ring" and other problems related to zero and his multiplicative inverse?**

**For example, if we will do that, can we convert problem, like:**

"Assume there was some number ⋆ that we add to the real numbers R with the property 0⋅⋆=⋆⋅0=1. From this it follows that for any number x∈R we have
x = x ⋅ 1= x ⋅ 0 ⋅ ⋆ = 0 ⋅  ⋆ = 1.

This is a contradiction of course, since there are real numbers that are not equal to 1.
Hence, you can't add a multiplicative inverse of 0 to the reals. If you attempt to, you end up with a structure where all elements are equal to 1, the zero ring."

**... into such problem:**

"Assume there were some numbers ω="infinities" and ε="infinitesimals"  that we add with the property ε ⋅ ω = ω ⋅ ε = 1. From this, it follows that for any number x ∈ R we have:

1. x  = x ⋅ 1 = x ⋅ ε ⋅ ω;
2. x ÷ ε = ω * x;"

P.S. Sorry for the poor explanation - I'm not a Mathematician ;D

Comment: Check out the hyperreals.

Comment: You can introduce whatever you want. Of course, doing so may bring down load-bearing walls and eliminate the usefulness of what you get.  The problem is you haven't mentioned what you want beyond "an inverse for zero" and nothing about what else you want to retain.  What structure do you want to wind up with in the end?

Comment: Maybe you're starting to address my last comment in the end.  You're defining some partial operations involving infinities and infinitesimals.  This suggests you still want some or most of the field structure, but I can't tell.

Comment: Sorry for these post-edits ;) - because I'm an amateur I'm trying to clarify my question. My point is - why we operating with zero when it clearly means "total nothing"/"values emptiness" so I naively think we must choose some absolute small, but existing values (and their inversions for balance) for applied/practical calculations to avoid problems generated by zero (but maybe it will generate more other problems, but I don't know which are)? P.S. Sorry I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: @eyeballfrog thank you for the advice - hyperreal numbers look extremely interesting